# Filter emails by inbox and gmail folder

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client, email-filter

I would like to filter my inbox to see only messages with one or more specific Gmail labels on them.

I can see emails in my inbox and the folder belonging to the specific label.

How can I combine the two? Are there search operators that I could use?